# How to sort posts on Reddit by number of comments?

Tags: sorting, reddit

How to sort posts on Reddit by number of comments? 
I'd find this more useful than sorting by votes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the search at the top (magnifying glass button) to search for something (or `*` to show everything) and select the options button (which looks like two switches) and select "Most Comments":

[image: search results: sort by]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, reddit doesn't offer many sorting options. You are forced to use their algorithm of what is and is not considered "relevant." The number of comments on a post is a factor in the algorithms for **hot** and **rising**, but that's it. The only way to achieve what you are after is via a third-party service, and I am not aware of any designed for that purpose.